# imagick console commands into PHP Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Can anyone explain me how to convert imagick cli command that are working fine into PHP code using Imagick pecl?
I am not familiar enough with syntax of `convert` command and it is complex for me to do it quickly.

You may not read this heap of text bellow, just help to convert cli command to PHP. :)

I have one partially transparent figure located on not transparent white background(original image). With filling that transparent figure some background color/image I'll have many colored figures on white background.

What i need now(and where imagick comes in): I need remove that white background on result image so the only colored figure stays there with some blured edges on transparent backround.

What i am doing:

1. I fill original image with black color to get more contrast black figure on white background. Next, remove white background with command:

   `convert ./black.png -fuzz 70% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white -channel A -blur 0x1 ./mask.png`

So i have some transparent mask to use in future.

2. Apply mask.png to some colored image(green.php) that was got from original too:

   `convert ./green.png -alpha Off ./mask.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite PNG32:result.png`

That commands have to be translated into PHP. Can anyone advice me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am ready to answer my question.

Prepare original image to use it as mask. Make partially transparent figure in black:

```
$blank = new \Imagick('./original.png');
$blank->setimagebackgroundcolor('#000000');
```

Make mask from blank in black color. Remove not transparent white background and make it fully transparent:

```
$mask = $blank->flattenImages();
$mask->floodfillpaintimage('none', 30000, '#FFFFFF', 1, 1, false, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$mask->blurImage(0, 1, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
```

So we have a mask image that consists only of figure we need(in black).
Now we want to have a green figure, take it:

```
$greenBlank = new \Imagick('./original.png');
$greenBlank->setimagebackgroundcolor('#00FF00');
$green = $greenBlank->flattenImages();
```

Now apply prepared mask to our $green.

```
$green->compositeImage($mask, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
```

That is all. We have got a green figure on transparent background.